# Is it possible to ReKey a GlobalKTable?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I want to ReKey a GlobalKTable (probably while initializing it, as I believe they are read only once created).

Is this possible?

I have two topics that I am working with in a Spring/Java Kafka Streams app. The first is not compacted, the second is. Both use Avro for their keys and values.

The app streams records from the first (non-compacted) topic, and attaches additional data from the compacted topic via `KStream#leftJoin`. The compacted topic has been brought into the app as a GlobalKTable, created via `StreamsBuilder#globalTable()` and needs to stay this way (I need every record from all partitions of the topic available in each instance of the app).

I know there is talk of supporting non primary key joins (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3705), but to my knowledge, I can't do this yet...

```java
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class StreamsConfig {

  @Autowired
  private MyCustomSerdes serdes;

  @Bean
  public KStream<AvroKeyOne, AvroValueOne> reKeyJoin(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {

    GlobalKTable<AvroKeyOne, AvroValueOne> globalTable = streamsBuilder.globalTable("topicOne", Consumed.with(
      serdes.getAvroKeyOne()
      serdes.getAvroValueOne()
    ));

    KStream<AvroKeyTwo, AvroValueOne> kStream = streamsBuilder.stream("topicTwo", Consumed.with(
      serdes.getAvroKeyTwo(),
      serdes.getAvroValueOne()
    ));

    kStream.join(
      globalTable,
       /**
        * the KeyValueMapper. I need to rekey the Global table as well to the
        * corresponding String (which it's data will have) if I want this join
        * to return results
        */
      (streamKey, streamValue) -> {return streamKey.getNewStringKey()},
      (/**ValueJoiner Deal**/)
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to ReKey a GlobalKTable (probably while initializing it, as I believe they are read only once created).
>
> Is this possible?

There is no direct support for this today. You already mentioned upcoming work such as adding [support to global tables for non-primary-key joins](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3705), but this is not available yet.

What you could do today: you can re-key (re-partition) the original Kafka topic into a new topic, and then read the re-keyed topic into your global KTable. Maybe this is an option for you.

Comment: Rekeying the original topic is a thought. Although, each instance of the app would only consume and rekey the records on the partition it is assigned to (is my understanding anyway, am I wrong about this?). 

The issue here is, I need all of the data from the topic (across all partitions) in each instance of the app, not just the data on it's assigned partition, hence the use of `GlobalKTable`

Comment: The re-partitioning can be done with a normal KStream/KTable, which will result in a new, re-partitioned Kafka topic. Here, it doesn't matter if an instance of your app can only see "its" keys -- unless the re-partitioning itself requires global information (this would be a rare case). Then, read the re-partitioned topic into a GlobalKTable, which makes all the data available to each instance in your app.